# Node/Express app doesn't see changes in my Pug view files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a Node/Express app that uses Pug/jade template engine and I can render everything well! But the problem is when I add/change/delete something in my `index.pug` file or if I comment every single line of code in `index.pug`. Or even change the rendered file in `res.render()` I don't see any changes on the homepage even if I manually stop and restart the server!

**I think it's because of caching in some way. But I have explicitly turned it off** See below.

Here is my `app.js` Configuration

```js
const path = require("path");
const logger = require("morgan");
const express = require("express");
const viewRouter = require("./routes/viewRouter");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Initialize app

const app = express();

app.enable("trust proxy");
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view cache", false);

// Server Static files. Because the CSS and JS won't work!

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") app.use(logger("dev"));

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", viewRouter);
app.post("/", viewRouter);
module.exports = app;
```

I added the `app.set("view cache", false);` later after seeing some solutions online. But it doesn't work

And here is my `viewRouter.js`

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const viewController = require("../controllers/viewController");

router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  res.status(200).render("index", {
    name: "Hello",
    todos: req.body.storage,
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

TL;DR:- My Pug file changes don't get compiled. Even after restarting the server manually

Comment: If you open it in an Incognito/Private window, do the changes get reflected?

Comment: No. They don't. Even if I open a new browser they don't get reflected.

Comment: do you run app locally or via a proxy?

Comment: It's not a caching issue then. What are you using to render your pug files into html? Because it sounds like that's most likely the issue.

Comment: @SonNguyen I don't get it. But I have a middleware that trusts proxies you can see above code. Other than that I don't know what you mean

Comment: @ChrisStanley I'm using Express. Which automatically does it. Without the need for any packages to do so

Comment: I asked because there seems like something running between express app and client that serves content from http cache, like a web server/proxy does. Open devtools > network > disable cache to see iits the case

Comment: I found out that my app wasn't using my Pug file at all but it was using my ``index.html`` because they were the same name. But now the question is. Why does Express use my ``index.html`` file from the ``public`` folder instead of ``index.pug`` that's in the ``views`` folder?

Comment: express.static() goes before other middleware so obviously it finds index.html (its default index file) and serves first

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue. And the process that worked for me is I simply saved my pug file again and then I run the server from starting like nodemon a.js and after that, it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I also faced a similar problem.
But nothing worked for me which is available on the web.

At last, I copied the contents of my current pug file, deleted it, made a new file, pasted the old code, and started watching it.
It solved the problem for me.